# Creating Custom Field Types with Additional Column Settings

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007, custom-field-type

I am trying to create a Custom Field Type which is same as `Multiple lines of text` field with the following additional:

- It has one extra text box in the `Additional Column Settings` section when creating the question

[alt text http://img685.imageshack.us/img685/3338/multilineoftextwithrefe.png](http://img685.imageshack.us/img685/3338/multilineoftextwithrefe.png)

- When rendering the question, the value in the text box to be displayed before the text box as a link

[alt text http://img218.imageshack.us/img218/1263/questionwithreference.png](http://img218.imageshack.us/img218/1263/questionwithreference.png)

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Thanks in advance!